# Relation between -ますよ and -ましょう

Tags: particles, verbs, etymology, suffixes

They sound alike. Are they cognate historically?

Morphologically, is よ in both cases a particle or part of the morpheme in -ましょう?

Comment: I think ましょ might be a sound change from the other surface form of the 未然形 of ます, which is ませ.  So, ませう -> ましょう.

Comment: @snailplane, oh, the long vowel. Sounds feasible, since you can trace a diphthong becoming a long vowel even in the spelling.

Comment: Not merely feasible, but well-documented. The historical spelling of 〜ましょう was indeed 〜ませう.

Comment: Zhen Lin, thank you! @snailplane, if you might post an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: (Though someone might have already said this) goo dictionary says the「う」is an auxiliary verb... ましょ+う[ませう]:［連語］《丁寧の助動詞「ます」の未然形＋推量の助動詞「う」》http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/208020/m0u/

Comment: @Chocolate, thank you! Now it's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer to your initial question is no. The historical/etymological spelling of 〜ましょう was 〜ませう, which is the expected form of the volitional, since the irrealis (未然形) stem of 〜ます is 〜ませ. Regular sound change explains the rest: せう becomes しょう.

The same story applies to the consonant-stem (五段活用) verbs: the old spelling for 行こう was 行かう (as seen [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aAffiche_%C3%A9migration_JP_au_BR-d%C3%A9b._XXe_s..jpg)) etc. However, something strange happened to the vowel-stem (一段活用) verbs; instead of 見む → 見う → **みゅう or せむ → せう → **しょう, these were replaced by the forms with 〜よう we know today.

Comment: @katspaugh, Zhen Lin -- I've lost the link at the moment, but apparently せ and し were at one point both pronounced with an initial sound of /sh/.  So せう == /sheu/ changing to /shoː/.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi makes it clear now, thanks!

Comment: @katspaugh, Zhen Lin -- More data from Shogakukan about the change: **補注**　一・二段活用の動詞に推量の助動詞「む」を伴ったもの、たとえば「見む」「上げむ」は、室町時代末までに「みう」「あげう」から「みょう」「あぎょう」のような融合したオ列拗長音の形に変化していたが、そこから再び動詞未然形と助動詞とが分かれて、助動詞「よう」の形を生じた。これが、近世にはいって、一・二段活用の動詞一般のこととなり、カ変・サ変にも及んだ。ただし、この変化は、東国で進んだものと思われ、現代の標準語のように、五（四）段活用の動詞には「う」が、その他の活用には「よう」が付いて、接続を補い合う用法は、近世後期江戸語で勢力を得た。

Comment: *Translation:* **Note:** The forms of *ichi-* and *ni-dan* verbs accompanied by supposition auxiliary *mu*, such as 見む{mimu} and 上げむ{agemu}, changed by the end of the Muromachi period [circa 1573] to form a fused long /o/ sound as in /miu/ and /ageu/ becoming /myoː/ and /agyoː/, but this then again underwent a division between the irrealis form of the verb and the auxiliary, producing verbal auxiliary *yō*. This then became the general auxiliary used with *ichi-* and *ni-dan* verbs in modern Japanese, and was even applied to *ka-hen* and *sa-hen* verbs [such as 来る and する].

Comment: [cont.] However, this change is thought to have happened in eastern Japan, and as in modern standard Japanese, *u* attaches to *go-dan* (*yo-dan*) verbs, while *yō* attaches to other verbs, with this complementary usage gaining prevalence in late modern Edo speech.